# Gaining access to zip every folder in "C:\"

Tags: .net, vb.net, directory, zip

I want to zip **every folder** in "**C:**" to another hard drive.
I am using following code:

```vb
strSource = "C:\"
strDestination = "D:\FileHere.zip"
Try
   ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(strSource, strDestination, CompressionLevel.Optimal, True)
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
  'This code is written in .NET 5.0
```

The "Apps" folder is copied correctly, but then I get the error message: *Access to path "C:\ Settings and documents" is denied.*
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBkoZ.png)

I have already ran the program as **administrator** with:  `level="requireAdministrator"` in app.manifest  , but I still **didn't gain enough access** to **zip this folder**.
Does anyone know how I can get higher access, so I am able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running the program under an account which is a member of the Backup Operators group?